# python tkinter show right widgets after Combobox selection

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am new to tkinter and am trying to create a GUI with a Combobox. If a certain value (`'new subgroup'`) is chosen, other widgets should appear (`label_4`, `label_5` and `label_6`). If any other value of the combobox is being chosen, `label_7` should appear.

The issue that I am having right now, is that this works only the first time! If I change my mind, and chose another value than first chosen, the labels that appeared through my first choice still stay, with the second choice just appearing on top of it.
How can I only see the labels I want to see, even after having changed my mind and chosen another value from the combobox?

The code is somewhat long, but the important part starts at `input_3`, the rest is just for a bit of context ;).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

#configure the root
root.title('Add nodes')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

#add frame on the root
frame_add = ttk.Frame(root)
frame_add.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame_add.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
frame_add.columnconfigure(2, weight = 1)
frame_add.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame_add.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
frame_add.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)
frame_add.rowconfigure(3, weight = 1)
frame_add.rowconfigure(4, weight = 1)
frame_add.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

#first row
label_1 = ttk.Label(frame_add, text = 'Label (name of the .json file):')
label_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'E')
        
label = ttk.Entry(frame_add)
label.insert(0, 'write label here')
label.grid(column = 1, row = 0, columnspan= 2, pady = 5)
        
#second row
label_2 = ttk.Label(frame_add, text = 'Node (name of the node \
in the graph database):')
label_2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'E')
        
Node = ttk.Entry(frame_add)
Node.insert(0, 'write node here')
Node.grid(column = 1, row = 1, columnspan = 2, pady = 5)

#third row
label_3 = ttk.Label(frame_add, text = 'Define subgroup of node:')
label_3.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = 'E')
        
selected_colour = StringVar()
input_3 = ttk.Combobox(frame_add, textvariable = selected_colour, )
input_3['state'] = 'readonly'
input_3['values'] = ['requirement', 'property', 
                     'measurement_calculate', 'measurement_value', 
                     'measurement_signal_characterization', 
                     'measurement_technology', 'calculate_value', 
                     'measured_variables_expression', 'main_function',
                     'part_function', 'partial_solution', 
                     'test_bed_module', 'electronics', 
                     'mechanical_structure', 'new subgroup']
width = len(max(input_3['values'], key = len)) + 2
input_3['width'] = width
input_3.grid(column = 1, row = 2, columnspan = 2, pady = 5)
            
#after having chosen a value from input_3, this shows (depending on the value):
label_4 = ttk.Label(frame_add, text = 'Please insert the \
properties and corresponding values of the new subgroup:')
label_5 = ttk.Entry(frame_add)
label_5.insert(4, 'Category')
label_6 = ttk.Entry(frame_add)
label_6.insert(1, 'Carateristic to save')
label_7 = ttk.Entry(frame_add)
label_7.insert(1, 'Test')

#event to read the choice on input 3 and show the different widgets
def retrieve(event):
    if 'new subgroup' == selected_colour.get():
        label_4.grid(column = 0, row = 3, columnspan = 3)
        label_5.grid(column = 0, row = 4, pady = 5)
        label_6.grid(column = 1, row = 4, pady = 5)
        label_7.destroy()
    else:
        label_4.destroy()
        label_5.destroy()
        label_6.destroy()
        label_7.grid(column = 0, row = 3, pady = 5)
                    
input_3.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', retrieve, "+")

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use `.grid_forget()` instead of `.destroy()` inside `retrieve()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I used `grid.remove()` and it worked! Thanks for your help though!